# Kepler's Third Law versus PBS Newshour "Planets Orbiting in Sync"

Tags: celestial-mechanics, solar-system, visualization

See the PBS Newshour story from 04Dec2023...

"Solar system with 6 planets orbiting in-sync discovered in Milky Way"
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUTPoINTqYM

...About 30seconds into the video they've got an animation explicitly showing all the planets orbiting their parent star with the same period. Didn't anybody tell those planets about Kepler's third law? How'd they do that?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_110067) explains what is actually happening. The PBS animation is wrong if it shows what you say.

Comment: @Ghoster Thanks. From that page, _the innermost planet orbits three times for every two times for the next planet out...the fourth planet orbits four times for every three times for the fifth planet_, etc. So that's not what the PBS video is showing. It shows one-for-one, for all six planets. So I take it the PBS video is wrong? (If it's PBS or Kepler, I'll go with Kepler:)

Comment: *So I take it the PBS video is wrong?* Yes.

Comment: You are referring to an "animation" that some PBS intern made by rotating a still cartoon of the system at a constant rate. An accurate animation is shown briefly at 1:15. The full animation (and more) is in the NASA article [here](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/news/1771/discovery-alert-watch-the-synchronized-dance-of-a-6-planet-system/).

Comment: @Puk Thanks for the additional info. (Guess that pretty much had to be the answer.)